# Module failing to import for unknown reason

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

The wtforms.ext module is failing to import and I'm not sure why

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
```

The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.ext'
```

I have installed wtforms with the following commands but it still returns the error.

```
pip install -U WTForms
pip install -U wtforms.ext
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Do you have this issue? https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/22026

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pip install wtforms-sqlalchemy
```

and after that you can import:

```
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
```

****NOTE**: Please note wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy changes to wtforms_sqlalchemy**

Answer (score 0):

I understand I might be be late to answer on this.  `wtforms.extension` is deprecated since version 2.0 and removed in WTForms version 3.0.  See the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/ext/).
So now you need to do this import - `from wtforms.fields import SelectMultipleField`
and instead of QuerySelectField, you need to use SelectMultipleField.